# Refresh counter content in jQuery Datatable plugin after deleting the row with ajax

Tags: jquery

am using the jQuery Datatable plugin for pagination, this plugin working fine, am trying to refresh counter content that are shown at the bottom of the pagination after deleting the row with delete function in ajax with jQuery. see the attachment.

[image: before delete]
whenever delete function is called than it delete the entire row properly but can't update the counter value at the bottom . whenever am refresh the page than it update the value

[image: after delete]

my code for delete function is:-

```
var conf = jQuery.noConflict();
conf(document).ready(function(){
conf(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
    //alert(conf(this).attr("id"));
proid  = conf(this).attr("id");
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r==true)
  {
        var url = "<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>/turnkey/index/deleteproduct/";
            conf.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:url,
            data: { 'proid':proid},
            success: function(msz){
            alert(msz);
            if(msz=="deleted") {
            conf("#hidepro"+proid).hide("slow"); 
            }
            else {
                //conf("#hidepro"+proid).hide();
            alert("product cant be deleted");
            }
            //console.log("chal hun");
            }
        });

  }
else
  {
 return false ;
  }

  });
});
```

suggest me where i did some changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some ID to count element. Lets say if count is within  then,

```
<div id='rec_cnt'>Your Count</div>
```

You need to add one line at,

```
if(msz=="deleted") {
            conf("#hidepro"+proid).hide("slow"); 
            $('#rec_cnt').html((parseInt($('#rec_cnt').html()) - 1))
            }
```